# How to share URL and copy to clipboard with URL change

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a map site with URL like this(1):

`https://mysite. com/map`

When user zoom/move on the map the URL will change according to the zoom level and coordinates of the map, the URL will be changed to something like this(2):

`https://mysite. com/map#23/119830.34234/180.2346/`

My problem is when I copy URL to clipboard or share them on social network only get first URL(1) or URL when refresh website. I want to copy and share the latest URL changed when user zoom/move on the map.

This is my code for share and copy to clipboard

**HTML**

```
       <div class="share">
            <span>Share</span>
            <nav>
                <a class="social-share twitter" href="#"></a>
                <a class="social-share facebook" href="#"></a>
                <a class="social-share zalo" href="#"></a>
                <a class="clipboard" href="#"></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

**Copy to clipboard**

```
var temp = $("<input>");
var url = $(location).attr('href');
$('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
  $("body").append(temp);
  temp.val(url).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
  alert('Copied!');
})
```

**Share to social**

```
setShareLinks();
function socialWindow(url) {
  var left = (screen.width - 570) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - 570) / 2;
  var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;
  // params = "";
  window.open(url,"NewWindow",params);
}

function setShareLinks() {
  var pageUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
  var tweet = encodeURIComponent($("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content"));

  $(".social-share.facebook").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl;
    socialWindow(url);
  });

  $(".social-share.twitter").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageUrl + "&text=" + tweet;
    socialWindow(url);
  });

  $(".social-share.linkedin").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=" + pageUrl;
    socialWindow(url);
  });
  $(".social-share.zalo").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://sp.zalo.me/plugins/sdk.js/?url=" + pageUrl;
    socialWindow(url);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the url when the user wants to copy it to the clipboard and not keep it ready on page load.

```
var temp = $("<input>");    
$('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  $("body").append(temp);
  temp.val(url).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp.remove();
  alert('Copied!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by [T.Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726687/20547594), you should remove the `href="#"` in your HTML. This will reset the location hash when the a-tag is clicked.